# Odoo 11 - Template XML t-foreach

Tags: python, xml, templates, odoo

I'm stuck for a loop in my Odoo template.

What I have done so far in image:

[image]

Here I retrieve members of a household via a loop

Clicking on one of the members here is what I programmed:
[image]

Here is the code of the first image:
[image]

Here is the code of the contents of the modal window:
[image]

What I want to do :

Just get the information of the member clicked and not all the information of all the members.

An idea ?

Thank you !